# Make file readable for system but not users

Tags: permissions, security, password

I want to set up a script that allowes me to display my emails on my bar, but i have to create a file containing my password for it. Is there a way to protect this file from beeing read by anyone, without denying my system the access to that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easily enough done with standard unix file permissions.

Assuming the file is named `emailcredentials.ini` located in `/home/errelion` and is owned by the user the script will run as, the command you'll want is

```
chmod 0600 /home/errelion/emailcredentials.ini
```

This will render the file readable and writable to the owner, but inaccessible to anyone else (aside from `root`, who is the superuser and can do what he or she damn well wants).